# CSS Selector Performance via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

It says [on here (http://api.jquery.com/first-selector)](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector) that
" To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first") "

Can someone pls give an example of this?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you are worried about performance: drop jQuery for [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.elements').filter(':first');
```

or:

```
$('.elements').first();
```

or:

```
$('.elements').eq(0);
```

More efficient than:

```
$('.elements:first');
```

This is the case with other jQuery selectors like `:has` versus `has` method.

Answer (score 2):

Example collecting all `DIV` , then filtering `:first`

```
var divFirst=$('div').filter(':first');
```

Can also use `first()` method which will also use `filter()` internally in jQuery

```
var divFirst=$('div').first();
```